# Is there any tab widget plugin supporting third party widgets?

Tags: widgets

I am searching such a tab widget supporting third party widgets, such as `YARPP`, `TOC+`, `Ultimate Tag Cloud`. The following two popular tab widgets doesn't meet my requirements.

- [WP Tab Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-tab-widget/): only
  supports: Popular Tab, Recent Tab, Comments Tab, Tags Tab
- [Tabs Shortcode and
  Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabs-shortcode-and-widget/):
  only supports: Text Tab (HTML is allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TAB PLUGINS**

[Widgets in Tabs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widgets-in-tabs/)

[Collapsible Widget Area](https://wordpress.org/plugins/collapsible-widget-area/)

[Section Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/section-widget/)

Ultimate Tabbed Widgets & [Shortcodes Ultimate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/) also do this. *Although*, they use shortcodes. *However*, you could add [Widget Shortcode Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-shortcode/) which creates shortcodes for your actual widgets. Then you can simply put these shortcodes inside a tabbed shortcode like the ones provided in [Shortcodes Ultimate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/).

---

**CODING METHOD**

Alternatively, create however many dynamic sidebars you want (1 for each tab) and just code it into a template.

---

**MEGA MENU METHOD**

You could also use a mega menu plugin. I recommend using [Ubermenu](http://wpmegamenu.com/) above all other options I've listed as it is by far the simplest and supports everything you want right out of the box. Another megamenu plugin that this could also be done with is [Max Mega Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/), but it would be a little trickier.

---

**PAGE BUILDER METHOD**

Lastly most all page builder plugins like [Visual Composer](http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431) have support for adding tabs in sidebars as well as widgets inside those tabs.

Comment: Thx. `Widgets In Tabs` is really what I am looking for, but I can **ONLY** one tag widget. How do I create several tag widgets?

Comment: I make it by adding a new WIT area.